# Moderator refuses to reopen my question even though there is no reason for it to remain closed

Tags: discussion, moderators

The moderator has put my question in "on hold" state. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292209/sql-query-from-python-vs-raw-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment64002403_38292209)

The moderator argued that the information provided was insufficient. I've updated the question, added more information and asked for re-opening the question.

The moderator keeps trying to answer by himself instead of re-opening it.

Comment: Let other the chance to reopen it. Once it was edited - It will go to the reopen queue for review and the community will vote about re-opening your question

Comment: It looks like it has three reopen votes already, so it is on its way. It looks like the decision to put it on hold was correct, but that can be reversed if it is now understandable to readers. Do please try to avoid hostile language here - Martin is not "refusing" to do anything, and he is is a (very busy) volunteer who is serving the community. Contrary to popular belief, mods _are_ allowed to leave their keyboards for a while `:-)`

Answer (score 22):

I don't think Martijn closed that question in his capacity as a moderator but in his capacity as a Python Gold tag badge holder. That his close vote is binding is just a side effect of being a moderator.

The [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38292209/1) was lacking the code you claimed was causing trouble. That would have been enough reason for any user with close vote privileges to close vote your question as ["lacking an MCVE"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

After Martijn checked back on your question he noticed the code you added. That made him realize he forget another possible reason for the differences you saw, so he left a polite comment to ask you about that.

It is a bit unclear why you didn't answer that comment but instead went down the route to meta, to ask the other volunteers here if they could assist with improving your question so it could get re-opened. Not much have to be done for that, after your edit, the question did hit the [re-open queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12959964) and I see that <s>already 2 users</s> enough users voted for leave open. Unfortunately(?) 3 users with delete privileges voted to delete your [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Fne.png). Coming to meta has not always the desired effect.

That doesn't mean the question can be answered if undeleted. I left a comment (which you responded to with an edit now, thanks) and so did one other user that you might want to address, as well as the comment from Martijn. You might be facing a local issue that only applies to your specific setup. We are good but we don't do magic.

Sometimes an exchange of comments is needed to get stuff clarified, while questions are put on hold during that process. That is no abuse, that is how this community likes to guarantee posts are up to the quality standards future visitors expect from us.

Comment: No Sir you are incorrect, please click on "show more comments", I did answer his comment.

Comment: I don't see `show more comments` and I don't see it in the chat transcript either. So unless stuff got so heated that comments have been deleted you might want to re-address those questions then.

Comment: me: What's the reason you put my question "on hold' ? – ogren 2 hours ago.   
the other user:
Because we can't reproduce this issue with the information provided. – Martijn Pieters♦ 2 hours ago
     
me: Now it has all the required information

Comment: You didn't answer *So how large are the rows, and are you getting all results in the DB browser or only the first 100 or so?*

Comment: That question I did not answer, perhaps I was a bit upset because the question remained "on-hold" after I did what was asked.

Comment: Now, my question was closed. I honestly feel the question was formulated properly. When it lacked code I quickly added what was needed, I don't see the reason why it should be closed.

Comment: OK, well, we all have our off-moments but in this case you got upset with the wrong person. Maybe learn from this that our quality guidance is strict and that we use comments to get things clarified. Carefully consider each comment and how to respond to them. If comments are unclear, don't hesitate to ask for clarification. The users that volunteer their time here try to help, so always assume good faith.

Comment: @ogren: I have voted to undelete.

Comment: @ogren you might want to address that comment you missed  as an edit in your question, if possible with other diagnostics you might have that are specific for your setup. More users might follow the suggestion from halfer   and then you want your question to be tip top to prevent new close votes.